# Why is my trigger incrementing by 2 instead of 1?

Tags: sql, oracle, auto-increment

This is my sequence

```
CREATE SEQUENCE exp_seq 
  START WITH 3 
  INCREMENT BY 1
  Cache 100;
```

trigger:

```
create or replace TRIGGER auto_increment_reimb_id
BEFORE INSERT ON EXPENSE_TABLE
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    if :new.exp_id is null
    then SELECT exp_seq.nextval into :new.exp_id from dual;
    end if;
  END;
```

My Sql insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO EXPENSE_TABLE(USER_ID,AMOUNT,TIME_SUBMITTED,DESC,STATUS,TYPE_ID) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

My first insert will increment by 1. But subsequent inserts increment by 2.
I do not pass in the pk id in my insert statement, and only call on it to update in the trigger. So I don't get why this is happening. 
On first insert, the pk column is 4.  On second insert, it becomes 6.

Comment: you are creating trigger on the EXPENSE_TABLE table, but you are inserting into MY_TABLE, you need to create trigger on the MY_TABLE, not on the EXPENSE_TABLE.

Comment: Check the table definition - do you have a default value expression for `exp_id`, e.g. `exp_seq.nextval`?

Comment: @theName Thanks for catching that. I edited the post. I changed the names of the tables when creating the post.  My inserts were working fine.  Just incrementing by 2

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Thanks! I went through the table definition and found that there was another auto increment trigger being called that I forgot to drop before. You pointed me in the right direction. Thanks again man :)

Comment: Unrelated, but: you can simplify the assignment to `:new.exp_id := exp_seq.nextval;`